# How do I connect two GPU's?

Tags: tensorflow, multi-gpu

This is my first time asking a question so please correct me if I am wrong.

I am currently trying to connect two gpu's(Tesla v100*2).
Currently using Windows Server2016. => also the reason why I can't access to the controller(system controller) to activate gpu's

[[image]]

```
Mon Aug 03 09:46:56 2020
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 425.25       Driver Version: 425.25       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name            TCC/WDDM | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla V100-SXM2...  TCC  | 00000000:00:05.0 Off |                  Off |
| N/A   32C    P0    37W / 300W |    370MiB / 32642MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla V100-SXM2...  TCC  | 00000000:00:06.0 Off |                  Off |
| N/A   36C    P0    38W / 300W |    370MiB / 32642MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|  No running processes found                                                 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have checked my usage by '''nvidia-smi''' and the above is the result I get.
I am running it on Tensorflow2.0.0 and I some how found out multi gpu's does not work well on the Tensorflow version 2.x  so I have downgraded to Tensorflow version 1.14. But still I cannot find the way to connect the two GPU's

Comment: The python version I am using is Python 3.6.7

Comment: Are you sure this is supported on a Windows OS at all? Multi-GPU support is severely limited when running under Windows, especially when the GPUs are not configured to run in "compute only" mode.

Comment: so what do you suggest me doing with it? should I just turn it to "compute only" mode and hope for the best? please help me out here it would mean a lot :(

Comment: Usual approach with multi-GPU would be to switch over to Linux straight away. I'm not even sure switching both of them to compute only mode would already be sufficient for your application.

Comment: well ill still have to find a way to make both gpu's run...

Comment: I have fixed it by setting my settings to Tensorflow1.14 and my pythonn to 3.5.6

Comment: @Keumdoh, for the benefit of community please can you elaborate steps you have followed to connect two GPU's in answer section.